# Android : Where are stored the data put into AccountManager

Tags: android, security, accountmanager

for my project I need to store a user identifier. I thought that maybe I could store it in /data/data/com.my.package/files but if someone root the phone it 's obvious that he'll search first here. So I thought why not use [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) that seems a bit safer (tell me if I'm wrong). So here's my question : Where are stored data put in the AccountManager ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AccountManager is not safer than using a file from the internal storage. The database with accounts is not encrypted and still can be accessed on a rooted device. This is a quote from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html#Security):

> It's important to understand that AccountManager is not an encryption
>   service or a keychain. It stores account credentials just as you pass
>   them, in plain text. On most devices, this isn't a particular concern,
>   because it stores them in a database that is only accessible to root.
>   But on a rooted device, the credentials would be readable by anyone
>   with adb access to the device.

This database can be found at `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db`, where 0 is user's ID.

Comment: That was a very good explanation.Thanks for the reference.Which could be a good option to store a credentials?

Comment: AccountManager actually is a good place to store user's credentials, just don't put a plain text password there, only an auth token. If you want to go further, you can encrypt your auth token before putting it into AccountManager. P.S. Please accept my answer if you think it was helpful.

Comment: @makovkastar Sorry for the late answer but yeah it was helpful ! I'm still a bit confused of how AccountManager work but with your answer and comment it will be easier to search how to store identifier that no one can have access to. Thanks